# Confused by effective type rules

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I seem to be missing a few pieces of the puzzle regarding effective type again... The comments in the code are essentially my question, but it's the only way I can think to ask this question with proper context.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct foo {
    int n;
} Foo;

int main(void)
{
    // No effective type yet because there has been no write to the memory.
    Foo *f = malloc(sizeof(Foo));

    // Effective type of `f` is now `Foo *`, except I'm writing to
    // `f->n`, so shouldn't it be `int *`? Not sure what's going on here.
    f->n = 1;

    // No effective type yet because there has been no write to the memory.
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(Foo));

    // Effective type of `buf` is `Foo *`, despite it being declared as
    // `char *`.
    // It's not safe to modify `buf` as a `char` array since the effective type
    // is not `char`, or am I missing something?
    memcpy(buf, f, sizeof(Foo));

    // The cast here is well defined because effective type of `buf` is
    // `Foo *` anyway, right?
    ((Foo *)buf)->n++;

    // I'm not even sure this is OK. The effective type of `buf` is `Foo *`,
    // right? Why wouldn't it be OK then?
    memcpy(f, buf, sizeof(Foo));

    // Safe if the last `memcpy` was safe.
    f->n++;

    // buf now points to invalid memory.
    free(buf);

    // Pointers with different declared types point to the same object,
    // but they have the same effective type that is not qualified by
    // `restrict`, so this doesn't violate strict aliasing, right?
    // This is allowed because `f` was allocated via `malloc`,
    // meaning it is suitably aligned for any data type, so
    // the effective type rules aren't violated either.
    buf = (void *)f;

    // `f`, and consequently `buf` since it points to the same object as `f`,
    // now point to invalid memory.
    free(f);
}
```

Am I correct in thinking that all of that is OK, or am I wrong in some cases? I realize this is borderline asking multiple questions, but I'm essentially asking whether my understanding of effective type and strict aliasing is correct. GCC produced no diagnostics for me with `-pedantic-errors -Wextra -Wall -O2 -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing`

Comment: `buf = (void *)f` is always valid (regardless of the type of `f`), simply because the strict aliasing rules have an exception that allows a `char *` to alias any other type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mixed up about what "effective type" applies to: it applies to the malloc'd space, not any pointer.   As always in C, a pointer is a separate object with separate properties to any space that the pointer may happen to point to.

`f` is a (named) variable so its effective type is always the same as its declared type, namely `Foo *`. Similarly `buf`'s effective type is always `char *`. The only time that the effective type may change at runtime is for dynamically allocated space.

Your bullet points and the code comments make little sense so I've decided to annotate your code afresh. The text refers to the code above the text in each case:

```
Foo *f = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
```

OK. Uninitialized bytes have been allocated and `f` points to them. The dynamically allocated space has no effective type yet.

```
f->n = 1;
```

The effective type of the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of dynamically allocated space is set to `int`. (* - but see footnote)

```
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
memcpy(buf, f, sizeof(Foo));
```

The `memcpy` function preserves effective type of objects copied, so the effective type of the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of the space pointed to by `buf`, is `int`.

```
((Foo *)buf)->n++;
```

Firstly, the cast does not have an alignment problem because `malloc` space is correctly aligned for any type. Moving onto the access of `n`, this is OK because `((Foo *)buf)->n` is an lvalue of type `int`, and it designates an object of effective type `int`. So we can read and write with no problem.

```
memcpy(f, buf, sizeof(Foo));
```

`memcpy` is always OK, as it sets the effective type (your comment suggested that memcpy might not be OK in some cases). This line sets the effective type of the space pointed to by `f`, to `int` (since the source space had effective type `int`).

```
f->n++;
```

Fine, same rationale as `((Foo *)buf)->n++` above.

```
free(buf);
buf = (void *)f;
```

Redundant cast. The space pointed to by `f` has effective type `int` still, since neither of those lines wrote to that space.

```
free(f);
```

No problem.

---

Footnote: Some people take a different interpretation of the expression `f->n` (or `((Foo *)buf)->n` w.r.t. strict aliasing.  They say that `f->n` is defined as `(*f).n` and therefore the associated effective type is the type of `*f`, not the type of `f->n`. I don't agree with that view so I won't expound on it further.  There have been proposals for C2X to clarify this situation and other grey areas of strict aliasing.  For your particular code, the code is still correct under either interpretation though.

Comment: I will just add that the return value of malloc should be verified. And that `Foo *f = malloc(sizeof *f);` is a good practice.

Comment: @Stargateur Agreed. For brevity, I omitted the verification from my question, and I used the type names to emphasize I was dealing with allocations, reads, and writes of the same size. Apologies for not mentioning that. :-)

Comment: "They say that `f->n` is defined as `(*f).n`..." They are wrong. It is C++ that defines `->` through an equivalent combination of `*` and `.`, but not C. In C language specification the `->` operator is defined independently.

Comment: *The effective type of the first sizeof(int) bytes of dynamically allocated space is set to int. (* - but see footnote)* This is not correct. When writing to members of a struct, values of padding bytes take unspecified values. This isn't a plain type int write. This is important because it shows that the effective type of the object is Foo, (and also int).

Comment: @2501 I note your view but don't want to have an extended discussion in comments - I'd suggest posting your own answer with your interpretation of the code . Discussion specifically of what `f->n = 1;` does w.r.t. effective type probably warrants its own question, rather than occurring in comments to this question.

Comment: You didn't write any arguments that back your point of view. Please do so.

Comment: @2501 I don't want to have an argument here sorry. Again I suggest writing your own answer (you can downvote this one if you don't like it)

Comment: I'm curious about your point of view, but you haven't provided any arguments for it. You're claiming it is so. Just write your arguments, so I can try to evaluate them.

Comment: @2501 My "argument" is that `f->n` is an lvalue of type `int` , and the strict aliasing rule says that writing through an lvalue of type `T` sets the effective type to `T`, etc.. I mention this in my answer

Comment: Ok, I understand. Standard is perhaps vague here. Still the compiler known how the int is written, because it is using the pointer, and must know that padding bytes are there.

Comment: Isn't `((Foo *)buf)->n++;` illegal? It casts a `char*` to a `Foo*`. The opposite is legal, but not this. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AvivCohn it's not illegal to cast a `char *` to a `Foo *`

Comment: @M.M I see. The `char*` object has a different effective type than the `Foo*` object, and thus it's illegal by the strict aliasing rule to access it through a `Foo*` (please correct me if this is false). So is the reason that `(Foo*)buf)->n++;` is legal, because the actual dereferencing happens through lvalue `int`, to bytes which are of effective type `int`?

Comment: @AvivCohn In the first sentence you seem to be conflating pointers with what they are pointing at ...  the `char*` object is a different object to the one being accessed after dereferencing the `char *` . The strict aliasing rule applies to the object being accessed, it makes no mention of pointers.   Your last sentence is roughly correct

Comment: what is the name for the proposal?

Answer (score 1):

```
// No effective type yet because there has been no write to the memory.
Foo *f = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
```

There are no accesses here and no objects. Effective type is not relevant.

```
// Effective type of `f` is now `Foo *`, except I'm writing to
// `f->n`, so shouldn't it be `int *`? Not sure what's going on here.
f->n = 1;
```

Object at the first sizeof(Foo) bytes at address f, has an effective type Foo, and the object at the first sizeof(int) bytes at address f has an effective type int.

```
// No effective type yet because there has been no write to the memory.
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
```

There are no accesses here and no objects. Effective type is not relevant.

```
// Effective type of `buf` is `Foo *`, despite it being declared as
// `char *`.
// It's not safe to modify `buf` as a `char` array since the effective type
// is not `char`, or am I missing something?
memcpy(buf, f, sizeof(Foo));
```

Object at the first sizeof(Foo) bytes at address but, has an effective type Foo, and the object at the first sizeof(int) bytes at address but has an effective type int.

Any object may be accessed with a character type regardless of its effective type. You may access bytes of buf with char.

```
// The cast here is well defined because effective type of `buf` is
// `Foo *` anyway, right?
((Foo *)buf)->n++;
```

Yes. The entire expression is valid.

```
// I'm not even sure this is OK. The effective type of `buf` is `Foo *`,
// right? Why wouldn't it be OK then?
memcpy(f, buf, sizeof(Foo));
```

This is ok. memcpy changes the type of object at address f to type Foo. Even if f didn't have type Foo before, it does now.

```
// Safe if the last `memcpy` was safe.
f->n++;
```

Yes.

```
// buf now points to invalid memory.
free(buf);
```

Yes.

```
// Pointers with different declared types point to the same object,
// but they have the same effective type that is not qualified by
// `restrict`, so this doesn't violate strict aliasing, right?
// This is allowed because `f` was allocated via `malloc`,
// meaning it is suitably aligned for any data type, so
// the effective type rules aren't violated either.
buf = (void *)f;
```

You mixing concepts. Restrict and values of individual pointers are not relevant for aliasing. Access is. Pointer buf now simply points to address f.

```
// `f`, and consequently `buf` since it points to the same object as `f`,
// now point to invalid memory.
free(f);
```

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid and—for having to deal with polymorphic data objects—was how it was done before C++.

However, there is not much more that can be extrapolated from those operations before one might shoot oneself in the foot.  That might occur from having `Foo` and say a type `Foo2` which is a different size and then access elements in one which are not there because the associated `malloc()` wasn't big enough.

Generally, it is more understandable and likely to be correct if the pointer type is always the same as the malloc().  For fancier morphism, c++ is likely to be less error prone (as long as its warnings are not suppressed).